# getting a nullpointer exeption error on java can't see what's wrong with switch

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, switch-statement

I got this simple piece of code that calls a method in another class that returns a string value. my program gets as far as the showinput box, i enter the search term and then the stupid nullpointer gets all over in my face. I am pulling my hairs here, not sure what to do. its case 3 that is killing me. All i get is java.lang.nullpointerexeption

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( menu);
        try
        {  
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);

        switch(i)
            {
                case 1:
                    f = new BasicFile();
              FileOpen = true;
              //BasicFile.Backup(f);

                display(f.getContents());
                break;

                case 2:
           if (FileOpen == true){
                    display(f.getLines(), (f.getWords() - f.getNumber()), f.getChars(), f.getNumber());
              }
              else
              display("Must open file first", "ERROR");
                break;

           case 3:
                    if (FileOpen == true){
              String key = input();
                    display(f.Search(key));
              }
              else
              display("Must open file first", "ERROR");
                break;

                case 4:
                    done = true;
                break;


                default:
                    display("This option is underfined", "Error");
                break;
            }
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException | NullPointerException | IOException e)
       {
            display(e.toString(), "Error");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Whenever you get a NPE, you need to carefully study the line that throws it. So which line is it? And are you checking if f is null first before using it?

Comment: Would you mind commenting out your try-catch block for a while and share the stacktrace that it will produce with us?

Comment: `f` is set in `case: 1` but used in `case: 3` - could it be that it is `null`? P.S. please use [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) when writing code; methods should be in `lowerCamelCase` - not least because not doing so plays havoc with SO's syntax hilighting.

Comment: @BoristheSpider let's wait for stacktrace before speculating...

Comment: All cases check if file was set on case 1 or they do not execute. But i can't comment out try-catch block, compiler throws a gazillion io exeptions at me. cause methods in the other class are throwing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four possibilities of null reference.

```
 1. FileOpen - might be null
 2. input() - might throw null
 3. f - might be null
 4. display() - might throw null
```

Check step by step what does throw npe, you can do it simply in debugger.